# Knockout checkbox always false

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a knockout checkbox and when it's checked it's being posted as false.  Any help would be appreciated
View:

```
<div class="managers" data-bind="foreach: managers">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="checkbox col-xs-12" data-bind="visible: isVerified == false && postalMessage != '' && postalMessage != null">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { checked: isCorrect, name: 'Personnels[' + $index() + '].IsCorrect' }"> <b>@AddressResource.IsCorrect</b>
                </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- .row -->
```

Javascript:

```
function Personnel(personnelId, firstName, middleName, lastName, primaryPhone, primaryPhoneExtension, secondaryPhone, secondaryPhoneExtension, fax, faxExtension, primaryEmail, secondaryEmail, postalAddress, city, state, zip, isVerified, isCorrect, postalMessage) {
        var self = this;
        self.personnelId = personnelId;
        self.firstName = firstName;
        self.middleName = middleName;
        self.lastName = lastName;
        self.primaryPhone = primaryPhone;
        self.primaryPhoneExtension = primaryPhoneExtension;
        self.secondaryPhone = secondaryPhone;
        self.secondaryPhoneExtension = secondaryPhoneExtension;
        self.fax = fax;
        self.faxExtension = faxExtension;
        self.primaryEmail = primaryEmail;
        self.secondaryEmail = secondaryEmail;
        self.postalAddress = postalAddress;
        self.city = city;
        self.state = state;
        self.zip = zip;
        self.isVerified = isVerified;
        self.isCorrect = ko.observable(isCorrect);
        self.postalMessage = postalMessage;
    }

    function KOViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.states = ko.observableArray();

        var modelStates = mStates;

        for (var i = 0; i < modelStates.length; i++) {
            var state = modelStates[i];

            self.states.push({
                id: state.Value,
                state: state.Text
            });
        }

        self.managers = ko.observableArray();
        var modelManagers = mManagers;

        if (modelManagers.length === 0) {
            self.managers.push(new Personnel(0, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
        } else {
            for (var x = 0; x < modelManagers.length; x++) {
                var personnel = modelManagers[x];
                self.managers.push(new Personnel(personnel.PersonnelId, personnel.FirstName, personnel.MiddleName, personnel.LastName, personnel.PrimaryPhone, personnel.PrimaryPhoneExtension, personnel.SecondaryPhone, personnel.SecondaryPhoneExtension, personnel.Fax, personnel.FaxExtension, personnel.PrimaryEmail, personnel.SecondaryEmail, personnel.PostalAddress, personnel.City, personnel.State, personnel.Zip5, personnel.IsVerified, personnel.IsCorrect, personnel.PostalMessage));
            }
        }

        self.addPersonnel = function () {
            self.managers.push(new Personnel(0, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually using the knockout checked binding. You're using the attr binding with the 'checked' attribute which probably doesn't have all the right event hooks. You just need to move the checked part outside of the attr binding's parameters to its own binding.

```
data-bind="attr: { checked: isCorrect, ...
//becomes
data-bind="checked: isCorrect, attr: { ...
```

Comment: It posted as `Personnels[1].IsCorrect:on`.  Is there a way for it to post as true?

Comment: Nevermind, added value="true" and it is working now.  Thank you!